# Why does pandas.where() returning 'None'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I was trying to use pandas.where() to remove negative values from a column in a data frame.

The most obvious way to remove the negative values is to simply run pandas.abs() on the column.  So:

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.DataFrame([-1,-1,-3,-4,-5],columns=["amount"])

frame.amount = frame.amount.abs()
```

But I wanted to try the same thing using pandas.where().  So I tried the following:

```
frame.amount = frame["amount"].where(frame["amount"] < 0, frame["amount"].abs(), inplace=True)
```

Which returns:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
  amount
0   None
1   None
2   None
3   None
4   None
```

Two things confused me:

- I was surprised I had to assign each expression (frame.amount = ...) because I thought calling the operation in either case would mutate the Dataframe (isn't that what 'inplace' should do?) and
- why does pandas.where() return 'None'

Comment: Use `frame.amount = frame["amount"].where(frame["amount"] > 0, frame["amount"].abs())`

Comment: Just change the `<` to `>` and remove the `inplace` parameter. Note that the `DataFrame.where` documentation states that `Replace values where the condition is **False**.`

Comment: Not sure why they differed from the `np.where` logic. This is kind of counterintuitive  + the docs on the `.where` method is not very explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
frame["amount"].where(~(frame["amount"] < 0), frame["amount"].abs(), inplace=True)
#frame["amount"].mask(frame["amount"] < 0, frame["amount"].abs(), inplace=True)
print(frame)
```

[`series.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) says:

> Where cond is True, keep the original value. Where False, replace with corresponding value from other.

So the condition has to be false for assigning.
Similar is [`series.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) which says:

> Replace values where the condition is True.

So we can use the same as well.

*Regarding `inplace=True`, when you use this, there is no need to assign the results back as `inplace=True` does the operation inplace which is as good as not using inplace and assigning the results back. `inplace=True` returns `None` which if you assign back to the series, you will be left will `None`*